# When adding point on dynamically created Multiple Highchart Graphs on a single page, the plot line draws to the start point instead of last point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, highcharts, drawing

```
var charts = [];
// change to an empty string to use the global namespace
var getChartConfig = function(renderId, title, data) {
    var config = {};
    config.chart = {
        renderTo: renderId,
        type: 'spline',
        width: 450,
        height: 300
    };
    config.title = {
        text: title
    };

    config.legend = {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    };
    config.yAxis = {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'watts'
        }
    };
    config.xAxis = {
        type: 'datetime'
    };
    config.tooltip = {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} watts</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    };
    config.series = [{
        name: title,
        data: data
    }];

    return config;
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/node/watts/data',
        success: function(msg) {
            var list = $.parseJSON(msg);
            $.each(list, function(i, item) {
                if (($('#node-' + item.nodeId + '-value').length) == 1)
                    series = item.data
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                    getChartConfig('node-' + item.nodeId + '-chart', item.name, series)
                ))
            });
        }
    })
    var i = 0

    function socketloop() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            i = i + 1
            requestData();
        }, 5000);
    }
    socketloop();
    setInterval(socketloop, 5000)

});

function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/node/watts/test/2',
        success: function(point) {
            var myObject = JSON.parse(point);
            console.log("============= " + myObject)
            $.each(myObject, function(i, item) {
                for (x = 0; x < charts.length; x++) {

                    if (charts[x].series[0].name == item.name) {
                        console.log("============= " + item.data)
                        shift = charts[x].series[0].data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                        charts[x].series[0].addPoint(item.data, true, shift);
                    }

                }

            });
            cache: false
        }
    });
}
```

I have two ajax calls to request the past data and the second ajax that retrives the newest point.
The Json consists of datatime and a watt value. With muiltple json objects by consisting of each node-ID, name, and data (timedate and value).

When it retrieves the past data it creates a chart with the data in the series and assigns the element id, title and data through the helper "getChartConfig" and pushs that chart to the charts array.

This renders fine but for the time doesn't display in the tooltip.
[image: Before addPoint is called]
But it calls the function requestdata() which gets the JSON of the latest DateTime and watt value. I parse the json and to the series i call the function addpoint and the data i send in this case it is item.data,(as im iterating over the parsed Json Array.

This is when the point is added and when the line draws from the start point of the history data instead of the end point of the history data.
[image: When addpoint adds new points]
Itseems to be as if it doesn't see the previuos data.

Any advice would be much appricated, as how to make the addpoint draw from the last point of the existing data.

Comment: Do you have an example of your JSON? What does `item.data` look like?

Comment: Please ensure that your data is sorted by x ascending and if "new Points" is "older" then last point from your json.

Comment: I had server returning the timestamps in descending order. So simple i overlooked it. Thank you Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your data is sorted by x ascending.